# Prestashop API error: Property Category->link_rewrite is not valid

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm try to modify a category through Prestashop API, but I got error:

**Validation error: "Property Category->link_rewrite is not valid"**

I'm using Postman to Put my changes, but even if I just copy and past the result of the GET in the body of the PUT call, the result give me this error.

this is what I send in the body of the PUT call:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <category>
        <id>
            <![CDATA[3]]>
        </id>
        <id_parent xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/categories/2">
            <![CDATA[2]]>
        </id_parent>
    
     
        <active>
            <![CDATA[1]]>
        </active>
        <id_shop_default>
            <![CDATA[1]]>
        </id_shop_default>
        <is_root_category>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </is_root_category>
        <position>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </position>
        <date_add>
            <![CDATA[2021-11-18 16:10:04]]>
        </date_add>
        <date_upd>
            <![CDATA[2021-11-18 16:10:04]]>
        </date_upd>
        <name>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[Clothes]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[Clothes]]>
            </language>
        </name>
        <link_rewrite>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[clothes]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[clothes]]>
            </language>
        </link_rewrite>
        <description>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[<p>Discover our favorites fashionable discoveries, a selection of cool items to integrate in your wardrobe. Compose a unique style with personality which matches your own.</p>]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[<p>Discover our favorites fashionable discoveries, a selection of cool items to integrate in your wardrobe. Compose a unique style with personality which matches your own.</p>]]>
            </language>
        </description>
        <meta_title>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
        </meta_title>
        <meta_description>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
        </meta_description>
        <meta_keywords>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/1">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/languages/2">
                <![CDATA[]]>
            </language>
        </meta_keywords>
        <associations>
            <categories nodeType="category" api="categories">
                <category xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/categories/4">
                    <id>
                        <![CDATA[4]]>
                    </id>
                </category>
                <category xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/categories/5">
                    <id>
                        <![CDATA[5]]>
                    </id>
                </category>
            </categories>
            <products nodeType="product" api="products">
                <product xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/products/1">
                    <id>
                        <![CDATA[1]]>
                    </id>
                </product>
                <product xlink:href="http://localhost/prestashop/api/products/2">
                    <id>
                        <![CDATA[2]]>
                    </id>
                </product>
            </products>
        </associations>
    </category>
</prestashop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please attach exactly what you are sending in, as this is too little information to answer your question in a meaningful way.
It is possible that what you are submitting is really invalid.

In PrestaShop, the link_rewrite fields must be of type URL.

If you use PHP to generate the value, you can use the `Tools::str2url()` PrestaShop method.